# JPA ORM.xml mapping file in <mapped-superclass> cannot put <basic> together <id > or <version >

Tags: java, xml, jpa, orm

I'm have many class with JPA Annotations and I need to change it to orm mappingfile.

But, there is a stranger error in the XML

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <entity-mappings version="2.1"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"   
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm 
                    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd">


<mapped-superclass class="model.base.BaseModel">
    <entity-listeners>
        <entity-listener class="model.base.BaseModelListener"></entity-listener>
    </entity-listeners>

    <attributes>


        <id name="id">
            <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY" />
        </id>

        <version name="version"></version>

        <basic name="createdAt" optional="false">
            <column name="updated_at" nullable="false" />
            <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
        </basic>

        <basic name="updatedAt" optional="false">
            <column name="updated_at" nullable="false" />
            <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
        </basic>

    </attributes>

</mapped-superclass>


<entity class="model.general.Account">
    <attributes>            
        <basic name="email">
        </basic>
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

if has < id> tag or < version> tag together < basic> show the error :

```
 cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'basic'. One of              {"xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm":version "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm":many- to-one, http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm":one-to-many, "    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/
         persistence/orm":one-to-one, "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm":many-to-many,  "http:// xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm":element-collection,    "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/ orm":embedded, http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm":transient}' is expected.
```

What's wrong? 
Can I define atribute in the superclass in .xml as defined in the model class with annotation?  T

he class with annotation are works with no problem, is there any limmitation using .xml than annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element `version` should occur immediately after last occurrence of `basic` element, not before them as it is now.

In this case right order is:

```
    <id name="id">
        <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY" />
    </id>

    <basic name="createdAt" optional="false">
        <column name="updated_at" nullable="false" />
        <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
    </basic>

    <basic name="updatedAt" optional="false">
        <column name="updated_at" nullable="false" />
        <temporal>TIMESTAMP</temporal>
    </basic>

    <version name="version"></version>
```

As a side note, column updated_at seems to be mapped twice.

This order of elements under `attributes` element is defined in [schema](http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd):

```
<xsd:sequence>
  ....
  <xsd:choice>
    <xsd:element name="id" type="orm:id" 
                 minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xsd:element name="embedded-id" type="orm:embedded-id" 
                 minOccurs="0"/>
  </xsd:choice>
  <xsd:element name="basic" type="orm:basic"
               minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  <xsd:element name="version" type="orm:version"
               minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  <xsd:element name="many-to-one" type="orm:many-to-one"
               minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
....
</xsd:sequence>
```